# Is there anything can be used instead of EntityRepository() decorator:

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

There is an error, EntityRepository is depreciated

```
`@EntityRepository(User)
    export class UsersRepository extends Repository<User>{
        async createUser(authCredentialDto: AuthCredentialDto): Promise<void> {
           const { username , password} = authCredentialDto;
           const user = this.create({username, password});
           await this.save(user);
        }
    }`
```